# Accessing object[] with different Type objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, visual-studio-2013

I am calling a third party service and in the Response they're returning an object[] called `Items`. This object array has a few different objects with different types inside its array.

Here's what the `Items` look like in the CS file:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("REPORT", typeof(REPORT))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("_PRODUCT", typeof(_PRODUCT))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("_PROPERTY_INFORMATION", typeof(_PROPERTY_INFORMATION))]
public object[] Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

I need to access the `_PROPERTY_INFORMATION` object inside the Items array. However, I am not sure what the best way is to approach such a task.

Here is what I ***currently*** have:

```
var items = RESPONSE.RESPONSE_DATA[0].PROPERTY_INFORMATION_RESPONSE.Items;
foreach (_PROPERTY_INFORMATION info in items)
{
    parsedStreetAddress = info.PROPERTY._PARSED_STREET_ADDRESS;
}
```

Is there a better way with less lines of code to accomplish the same thing? I'm just getting each `_PROPERTY_INFORMATION` that's inside the Items array.

Comment: Are you only expecting there to be one `PROPERTY_INFORMATION` instance in `items`? Or do you just want the last one?

Comment: Check the type of each item - if it's the type you're looking for, then cast and access the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using LINQ

```
_PROPERTY_INFORMATION result = RESPONSE.RESPONSE_DATA[0].PROPERTY_INFORMATION_RESPONSE.Items
    .First(x => x is _PROPERTY_INFORMATION);
```

Comment: This worked for me! Exactly what I was wanting.  I didn't think about using LINQ for this.  I greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Turp Its always nice to help